# How do I use JObject if the names are slightly different?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, model-view-controller, json.net

I have a JObject from JSON.NET with the following:

```
var jOBject =  {"schedule.ID" : 1, "schedule.Name" : "NameSchedule"}
```

The above is what I get from using Javascript to return the ID's and values of textboxes in the MVC Form in my View.

In my controller using C#, I would like to convert it into a Schedule Object that has the following Properties:

```
public class Schedule {
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
 }
```

I cannot do a

```
Schedule sched = jsonObject.toObject<Schedule>();
```

because the names are slightly different as the properties on the Jobject is prepended with 'schedule'.

Is there a query or a way to do the conversion that allows me to remove the 'schedule' in the jsonObject such that I can do the simple conversion in one line?

Comment: I think you should tag `java` instead of `javascript`

Comment: *"I have a JSON example Object with the following in javascript:"* That's neither valid JSON **nor** valid JavaScript.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu: No, those class code samples are C#, not Java.

Comment: You can't have `.` characters within JavaScript object property names unless the entire name is wrapped in quotes. Your current example throws: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `.`*. `schedule.ID` is invalid, `"schedule.ID"` is valid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haven't used C# at all. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu: :-) Looks a **lot** like Java, eh? The clue here was the `{get; set;}` on `ID` and such: Those are C# automatic getter/setter properties.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, a lot similar to Java :)

Comment: Are you sure what you're really trying to do is model binding in MVC? That syntax (`object.property`) looks a lot like what the default model binder will just do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to get it working is to use the [`JsonProperty` attribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to specify what JSON key you want to map to a certain C# property:

```
public class Schedule 
{
     [JsonProperty("schedule.ID")]
     public int ID {get;set;}

     [JsonProperty("schedule.Name")]
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can just use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize your JSON into a `Schedule` instance:

```
var schedule = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Schedule>(json);
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nml9be

Answer (score 0):

To use different key names in the JSON, you can decorate your C# class with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes.

```
[DataContract]
public class Schedule {
     [DataMember("schedule.ID")]
     public int ID { get; set; }

     [DataMember("schedule.Name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Actually `.` is a perfectly valid character in a JSON object's key

Comment: Ah yes you are correct. However when I answered there were no quotes around the key names which would be invalid JSON. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
JObject scheduleObj={schedule:{"ID" : 1, "Name" : "NameSchedule"}}

JsonSerializer seria = new JsonSerializer();
            Schedule oSchedule = new Schedule();
            if (ScheduleObj["Schedule"] != null)
            {
                oSchedule = (Schedule)seria.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(ScheduleObj["Schedule"]), typeof(Schedule));
            }
```